# Mocking Guzzle client inside Laravel job for testing

Tags: laravel, api, testing, guzzle, mockery

I have a job class which purpose is to send some user data to HubSpot, and to do that it uses Guzzle client to call the [create or update](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/create_or_update) API endpoint since the HS PHP client seems to lack this feature.

The problem is that during job testing I don't want to really call HS API, so **I need a way to mock the Guzzle client from the outside** of the job, but I can't find none.

I've also thought to add the client as a constructor arg and create the job via the service container to take advantage of Laravel's dependancy injection system, but I've discarded the idea since the job is never called/created in the application via service container and it therefore require to update the entire application where needed.

How can I test the job without really making a call to the HS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [Http::fake method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing) in your tests. e.g.:

```
Http::fake([
    // Stub a string response for Google endpoints...
    'google.com/*' => Http::response('Hello World', 200, $headers),
]);
```

And I would pair this with my new favorite test helper for [Preventing Stray Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#preventing-stray-requests) that will throw exeption if you have real HTTP requests called from your tests:

```
Http::preventStrayRequests();
```

Comment: I didn't know about this feature, it is really useful indeed

Comment: Beyod faking calls, is there a way to test that my job calls a specific url, eventually with a specific paylod?

Comment: Found it: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#inspecting-requests